# Objective-C: Lazy loaded models pattern

Tags: objective-c, design-patterns

I have objects, more precisely models, some properties of which are lazily loaded, i.e fetched on read, from a server. At the moment, I apply the classical technique, e.g.

```
@synthetize description = _description;
- (NSString *)description {
    if (!_description) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        _description = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url 
                                 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                 error:&error];
        if (error) {
            _description = nil;
            // error handling
        }
    }
    return _description;
}
```

However, it involves a lot of code repetition. Of course, I still can have a generic method  doing this and calling this method in all the getters (that's what I do). But do you have a better idea ?

**EDIT:** To make the code safer as suggested in comments. Here is another suggestion:

```
@synthesis description = _description;
- (NSString *)descriptionWithCompletion:(void (^)(NSString *description, NSError *error))completion {
    if (!_description) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            NSError *error = nil;
            _description = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url 
                                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                     error:&error];
            if (error) _description = nil;

            completion(_description, error);

         });
    }
    completion(_description, nil);
}
```

Comment: This is not a good pattern! Your caller can't handle the resulting error, and you're blocking the calling thread until the network access is complete. This is a really good way to have the UI stutter and have your app killed by the OS. You might instead want to indicate to the user of your models that accessing those values is asynchronous and potentially fails by having them pass you a completion block (which takes an optional error) instead.

Comment: So, you suggest to make the user pass a completion block to the getter. Then, dispatch the fetching process in a background queue which will call the completion block with the object and the error as parameters. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. This is somewhat painful for the caller, though, so you'll probably want to reduce the number of these asynchronous methods if possible, say by loading the whole model at once.

Comment: I put an example above. Hum, any idea concerning how to limit the code repetition except by doing a `#define` which declares the getters and avoid all the `- (NSString *)prop {return [self _genericGetterForProperty:_prop];}`.

Answer (score 0):

So, you're trying to reduce the boilerplate of methods like this:

```
- (NSString *)prop {return [self _genericGetterForProperty:_prop];}
```

Using a macro is one option; it would reduce the amount of text, but you still need a line for each method, so it's not clear to me that's it's really worth the extra complexity.

There is a way you could do this via [dynamic method resolution](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtDynamicResolution.html). Essentially, you implement `+ resolveInstanceMethod:` on your class. It will be called if someone tries to call a method on your model object that you haven't supplied at compile time. You can implement it to check the selector passed to see if it matches your `xxxWithCompletion:` structure. If it does, you can build an implementation based on the "xxx" value and add it to your class. You could prevent the compiler from warning you about this by declaring your properties as `@dynamic` or by explicitly suppressing warnings via pragmas.

I don't recommend it, though. It's a complicated and tricky solution; unless you've got hundreds of these properties, I would just write the boilerplate. (Or write a script to write the boilerplate.)